# How to build an analytics dashboard using react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-admin

I need some support or guidance on how to build an analytics/stats page using react-admin. I've googled ways to do so but I have found nothing so far and it looks like react-admin is too tight in the sense of customization.

### What I need

So basically I need a way to count the number of posts, users, or even comments from a `resource`. Something show like this:

[image]

Can be seen as something like this on another independent page:

[image]

But basically, something where you can grab the data from your data provider and render it like a normal analytics board or something like that.

Is this a possible way to do it in react-admin? Are there other ways, like another 3rd party integration that could help me with this? Any suggestions I'll appreciate them!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you will have to:

- Create a dashboard
- Pass as a parameter to `react-admin` component.

Example: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html#using-a-custom-home-page

In your dashboard, you will have to get the information and draw with other libs, and use an API to get the information.

Comment: Cool, let me try this then and come back!!